# Python line break printing twice

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

For some reason, whenever I try to print a 2D array using the following code, the `\n` prints twice.

```
array_test = [
  ['#', '#'],
  ['#', '#']
]

for i in range(0,2):
  for j in range(len(array_test[i])):
    print(array_test[i][j], end='')
  print("\n")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`print` automatically includes a line break.

`print("\n")` therefore prints 2 line breaks.

Comment: Oh, so if I do just `print()` or `print("\n" end='')` it will work. Gotcha!

Answer (score 3):

By default, Python automatically puts a newline at the end of `print()`. If I were to use this code:

```
print("hi")
print("hello")
```

this would be the output:

```
hi
hello
```

To use only one newline, you could simple use `print()`:

```
print()
```

or use `sys.stdout.write('\n')`:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```